# Will VMX cpu flags increase the speed of virtual machine software , like VirtualBox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

On some CPUs, if I run `grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo`, I can see a `vmx` flag under the `features` entry. Will this feature speed up virtual machine software like VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VMX CPU flag indicates hardware support for virtual machines on Intel CPUs (on AMD CPUs, the flag is SVM).

In general, yes, this speeds up virtual machine software that takes advantage of these CPU extensions.